# how to replace the hardcoded values from data provider

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider

I'm looking for the recommendation of removing (replacing) the hard-coded browser/OS/Version values from 
@DataProvider public static Object[][] sauceBrowserDataProvider. The code example:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "hardCodedBrowsers", parallel = true)
    public static Object[][] sauceBrowserDataProvider(Method testMethod) {
    return new Object[][]{

            **new Object[]{"firefox", "55.0", "Windows 10"},
            new Object[]{"chrome", "65.0", "Windows 10"},**

    };}


@Test( dataProvider = "hardCodedBrowsers")

    public void createDriver(String browser, String version, String os)
        throws Exception {
        Class<? extends TestRemote> SLclass = this.getClass();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // set desired capabilities to launch appropriate browser on Sauce
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, browser);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, version);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, os);    

        capabilities.setCapability("seleniumVersion", "3.8.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("name", SLclass.getSimpleName());
        capabilities.setCapability("screenResolution", "1920x1080");

        driver = (new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + SAUCE_USERNAME + ":" + SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities));

       configRead = new ConfigFileReader();

       propertyRead = new PropertyLoader();

       baseUrl = propertyRead.getProperty("site.url");

       app = new Application(driver);

       getURL();

    }
```

This is a selenium project on Java/ TestNg/ Jenkins/Saucelabs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this would be to Move the combinations(browser/OS/Version) to a data source like an excel spreadsheet or a csv or a json/yaml/xml and have your `@DataProvider` read them from there.

**Update**

- How to read a JSON file : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonparser.html
- How to read an XML file : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: would you mind to advise how to make Data Provider read a json or xml file?

Comment: @Y_Sh - I have edited my answer and included links that can help you learn them. Please go ahead and accept my answer, if your question has been answered.

Comment: thank you! Have another question: in case of extending this class by another Test class (ex. Login class), how can I make selenium to run the Test method from Login class also. Currently it only runs the Test method from the class where dataprovider is (the Basic class)

Comment: @Y_Sh That is not correct. TestNG by default runs all methods (both that reside in the current class and the ones that are inherited from a base class). If you are facing issues, you should be posting a new question for that instead of combining that here.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - How about a properties file instead ?

Comment: You can try [TestNG  with qaf](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [QAF TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks). It providers different [inbuilt data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) to load test data from different data source like xml, json, excel, properties, database. With QAF you can set different data source as below:

```
@QAFDataProvider (dataFile = "resources/data/logintestdata.csv")
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls")
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls", sheetName="login")
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/testdata.xls", key="login") //excel with data table
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/logintestdata.json")
@QAFDataProvider(key="login.data") //xml key
@QAFDataProvider(sqlQuery = "select col1, col2 from tbl") // database
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "resources/data/logintestdata.txt")
```

Moreover you can [switch data-provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#configureoverride-dataprovider) without change in code.  In addition to that it has lots of features for black box testing of web, mobile (using selenium, appium) and web-services.