# Should we call APIs inside TestNg DataProviders?

Tags: testng

Say I have a scenario where I have to test an API GET Something. To test this API, I need to create some test data using completely unrelated APIs. Lets call them Data APIs.

Is it ok to call the Data APIs in the DataProvider instead of the test class ?

PS - I google for answers and only saw one link which is not really relevant to my question. [how to replace the hardcoded values from data provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143354/how-to-replace-the-hardcoded-values-from-data-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, it's much better to access your Data API inside DataProvider.

Test method/class shouldn't contain any logic related to data manipulation. Test steps only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your test design and needs. Data driven test are used to iterate same test with multiple data set. If you are iterating the same test case with multiple data set then data-driven feature is best fit solution. You can utilize data-driven capability even for single set of data but you should think alternate by using setup methods and choose the best fit one.

For example, when using [TestNG's QAF extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) for [web-service testing](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki) you also can have background in BDD and before method in Java to setup data and use that data in request call. For example:
JAVA:

```
userRequests("get.sample.call", data);
```

BDD:

```
user requests "get.sample.call" with data "${data}"
```

If you are not iterating the same test for multiple data set, with qaf you can add additional `meta-data` let say `test-data-req` which provides request key for web-service call to get data. In before invoke testng mehod that meta-data can be used to do web-service call to populate `data` for test case.